# Calculate ground fault current leak on human contact

Tags: ground, fault

I am sure this is very very simple and probably realy dumb but I've been banging my head for hours and can't figure this out. Or find an answer on google/books for that matter. [image: 1]

Even with the diagram on the right i can't figure this out. This is supposed to be a demonstration of the function of how and when an rcd trips. To simulate it we used an appliance (in this case a washing machine) that is not properly insulated and the person touching the chassis.

D is the insulation fault resistance, T is the earth conductor resistance, and H is the body resistance.

I want to calculate Id (leakage current), the contact voltage and Ih (current in the person).  Voltage and resistance values are given but I want to calculate the currents for multiple values.

Comment: What have you figured out so far?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "what have you figured out". I know that part of the current will go through It and the rest through Ih. How much depends on the resistance of T. That's about it.

Comment: If the fault is the path for T, then the current is I= V(Ph)/R(D+H)  but the value for H is not a resistor but rather R1+R2//C ok?

Comment: This is an analogy to the "Human body model" that engineers use to calculate shock hazards. Use that as a search term to find out a lot more.

Comment: @Sparky256  almost, the HBM is 100pF used for ESD discharge which is different than the dielectric breakdown and impedance of a palm model at 50,60Hz , 100pF is only be 25 Mohm at line f but near 0 Ohms @ 300MHz. Leakage capacitance in a hand or clenched finger could easily exceed 10nF and drop to 50k

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist My understanding is there are several HBM types upon which one or more can apply to specific appliance types.

Comment: It's not the appliance but rather the contact area of ESD is very small thus 100 pF but leakage current depends on area of hands or feet etc so there is no model per se but there is a pain threshold for current.  which is why 0.5mA is max filter leakage ground current.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist for the purpose of the exercise H is a plain old resistance of 100 ohms or 1k ohms (again, this is a theoretical exercise). V(ph) is 23 or 230V.

Comment: If you're treating everything as resistance, you can calculate the resistance of H and T in parallel, and then the resistance of that in series to D.  The total resistance will tell you the total current, which will give you the voltage drop over D, and you can subtract that from the phase voltage to find the voltage over T and H, which will make it easy to calculate the current.  If you did need to use impedance instead of resistance because of capacitance or inductance, you can actually work it out in the same pattern with the correct formulas.

Comment: The max ground fault current is defined by the accumulation of ground filter current with a open ground, or the leakage of insulated ungrounded tools from line to hands and any imbalance of Line and Return currents.  So if you leave H in, is that the fault resistance value of choice you made?  Normally it must be <=0.1 Ohms

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist i've lost you completely there. H is supposed to be the resistance of the human body. it was pre-determined for the purpose of the exercise.

Comment: Is this more or less what you're wondering?  What formulas to use and how to put them together?  If you want to test a bunch of sample values, you can use a spreadsheet to break it down quite easily.

Comment: @KH that's prety much it. that's why I said it's very very simple and dumb. all I was missing was 1 step. For some f-ing reason I thought and was convinced somehow that contact voltage was the same as V(Ph) and thus was getting some hilariously bad results. It's been a few years since I've had to use this knowledge.

Comment: Ah yes.  I'll write a proper answer in a bit here then.